# Flutter/Dart: get_cli add more view to a page

Tags: flutter, dart, get-cli

How to add a multiple sub-view to a view with get-cli?
I add views manually but, is there any easier way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type the command `get create view:SubViewName on home` in the terminal.

home is your view you want to add a subview to.